# Azure Blob Storage : buffer cannot be null

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I'm following the source code from Xamarin for Azure : [FileUploader](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WebServices/AzureStorage/FileUploader/CS/ImageFileUploaderPageCS.cs) for Image Upload , and I try to run the app, the error shown the buffer cannot be null.
as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, Creating "MemoryStream object" and assign using stream.CopyTo(), return byte[] using "memorystream object".ToArray()

If you don't want to change the code as above,
1. Check the value of "stream.Length" 
2. Add some padding (extras) to it e.g. byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length+10] 
3. Also, check if you can read the stream using .CanRead()